# Laravel Scope Query throwing Grammar.php exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, query-builder

I have the following scope set up in a Model:

```
public function scopeInbox($query, $order = 'desc'){
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;

    return $query
        ->where('current_inbox','=',$userId)
        ->join('users', 'messages.created_by', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('users as forwarder', 'messages.forwarded_by', '=', 'forwarder.id')
        ->select('messages.*', 'users.name', 'forwarder.name as forwarder')
        ->orderBy('updated_at', $order);
}
```

And the following in it's related controller:

```
public function inbox()
{
    $messages = Message::inbox();

    return response($messages->get());
}
```

And Laravel keeps throwing the following exception:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given
```

Any ideas, S/O?

Comment: `scopeInbox` ? `Message::scopeInbox`?

Comment: My code is pretty much exactly per the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes "scope" isn't supposed to be necessary.

Comment: Your code is correct as far as the Query Builder syntax goes. Are you sure the error is coming from there? You didn't include the file and line where the error is triggered.

Comment: I query the same scope and have no errors..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply to your comments and thank you all for the input. Is it possible this has to do with my routes.php? I have a resource based route for standard routes like index, store, destroy, and then I have a couple of get/post routes. One of which is `Route::get('messages/inbox','MessagesController@inbox')` It was actually working before when I had a /{id} at the end of the route and was using that to select the inbox, but I want to select based on the authenticated user instead and trying to set it up in that way broke what I had working.

Comment: I'm not at my machine atm, unfortunately, but I can post some more thorough code this evening if a solution still isn't obvious

Answer (score 0):

You have two aliases called "forwarder" -- one of the users joins and the forwarder.name.

In something of a logical loop, you are attempting to alias an attribute of an aliased table with the same alias given to its table when you state "forwarder.name AS forwarder".

It might not be what's causing your error, but that is grammatically confusing, though technically valid. This would be my guess, but I have not verified it.

Bogdan's comment is correct. More information is needed. The file and line number where the error occurred and possibly a full stack trace could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the details Trip, but this was not the issue, unfortunately. I've posted my findings if you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

Bogdan's response was, indeed, correct. The issue was not coming from my implementation of the scope query, but instead had to do with the way my routes were set up. I had set up the following resource route:

```
Route::resource('messages', 'MessagesController',
    ['only' => [
        'index',
        'store',
        'show',
        'destroy'
        ]
    ]
);
```

Which was preventing my inbox route from being available:

```
Route::get('messages/inbox', 'MessagesController@inbox');
```

The solution here, was to break out the resource routes into individual get/post routes.

```
Route::get('messages/index', 'MessagesController@index');
Route::post('messages/store', 'MessagesController@store');
Route::get('messages/show', 'MessagesController@show');
Route::get('messages/destroy', 'MessagesController@destroy');
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to define custom controller methods as resource accessible, but I couldn't find anything in the Laravel docs. So, this solution works, but I would definitely accept another answer that provided a more proper solution to this.

Anyways, thanks for the insight, S/O!

Comment: I think this would have worked if you didn't use 'only'. If you aren't happy with your solution, you can just define a normal resource route and then add your 'inbox' route. If you are super concerned about a defined /destroy route, you can manually block it by adding a redirect response for it in your controller.

Comment: Thanks, Trip -- I actually came to discover that my issue was that I was defining my routes after the resource route. By placing the custom routes before the resource route, I was able to keep both implementations. How would I add the inbox route to the resource, though? I thought the resource routes were restricted to a particular set?

Comment: It's really just an extra route and method, not some magical new resource route. You can just define it separately. Route::resource('message', 'MessagesController'); Route::get('message/inbox', 'MessagesController@inbox');